# Связывание объектов в контексте спринг

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

```
<bean name="tester" class="org.dbunit.DefaultDatabaseTester">
    <constructor-arg ref="testDatabaseConnection" />
</bean>

<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
    <property name="datatypeFactory">
        <bean class="org.dbunit.ext.oracle.Oracle10DataTypeFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="caseSensitiveTableNames" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="testDatabaseConnection" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig"/>
</bean>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, почему при создании объекта  `org.dbunit.DefaultDatabaseTester` возможно передать в конструктор объект типа 
`com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean`? Ведь конструктор принимает в качестве параметра объект типа `IDatabaseConnection`!

Answer (score 4):

[`com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean`](https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/blob/master/spring-test-dbunit/src/main/java/com/github/springtestdbunit/bean/DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean.java) - это реализация [`org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). С такими бинами Spring работает иначе, их экземпляры не внедряются напрямую, а используются для создания экземпляров других бинов.

Внедряемые бины возвращаются методом `getObject()`, в вашем случае это `org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSourceConnection`, который реализует `IDatabaseConnection`.

- https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean - пост про `FactoryBean`.